# checking the page exist or not using javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if page exists using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922989/how-to-check-if-page-exists-using-javascript)

How to check the page is exist or not using javascript.