# checking the page exist or not using javascript and ajax

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if a page is exist or not using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922989/how-to-check-if-a-page-is-exist-or-not-using-javascript)

can you provide the code for checking the page exist or not.if not,it will redirect to another page.

Comment: duplicate of your same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922989/how-to-check-if-a-page-is-exist-or-not-using-javascript

Comment: I'm sure someone at freelancer.com or project4hire.com would be more than happy to give you a quote

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, if the page doesn't exist (the server is given what it considers an invalid url that it cannot satisfy), you will get a 404 error. So no code on any target page is going to run. Instead you have to do this server side, specifying what page to serve instead when a 404 is encountered. It is not done with client-side javascript.

Comment: See duplicate question, there are ways to do it in javascript