# Embed video link checker script on html website

Tags: javascript

I was looking for a solution to write a script which warns if the embed video on the website has been deleted or removed on the video provider site such as Youtube, Vimeo.

I looked everywhere, but i cannot find any solution on this subject.

Comment: You should check the API docs for each video provider. They should have some handling code for that.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
function isURLReal(fullyQualifiedURL) {
    var URL = encodeURIComponent(fullyQualifiedURL),
        dfd = $.Deferred(),
        checkURLPromise = $.getJSON('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22' + URL + '%22&format=json');

    checkURLPromise
            .done(function(response) {
                // results should be null if the page 404s or the domain doesn't work
                if (response.query.results) { 
                    dfd.resolve(true);
                } else {
                    dfd.reject(false);
                }
            })
            .fail(function() {
                dfd.reject('failed');
            });
    });

    return dfd.promise();
}

// usage
isURLReal('http://google.com')
        .done(function(result) {
            // yes
        })
        .fail(function(result) {
            // no, or request failed
        });
```

Full details here : [StackOverFlowLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922989/how-to-check-if-page-exists-using-javascript)

Comment: So if I get it right, This is redirecting if the url access fails.