# How to check if a page exists or not using AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs, jsp, iframe, angularjs-directive

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922989/how-to-check-if-page-exists-using-javascript) except the fact that I am looking for AngularJS based solution for this problem.

I have an `iframe` in my JSP page and `src` of this iframe is a page in **another domain** I want to show an image from the `images` folder if `iframe` is unable to load the `src` page.

I can't find a reliable way to check (or get notified when response arrives) about the availability of cross domain pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching more about the problem I came to know that problem is because my requests are Cross-Domain and browser can't allow such requests due to security. Because if that is allowed Internet security will be insane to handle. I found [a very good](http://jvaneyck.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/cross-domain-requests-in-javascript/) post which explained everything in detail.

I tried using JQuery, JavaScript everything even the JSONP requests were not working since I had no access to the other server. So I used the solution of Server Side call in my code. In Short I did following things

1. Created a new Servlet (This is the only servlet in my demo project if you have existing servelt you can just add a new case).
2. Inside the **processRequest** method added call to the second server (third party).

   ```
   protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
               throws ServletException, IOException {
           httpServletResponse.setContentType("image/png");
           String url = "http://www.w3schools.com/angular/pic_angular.jpg";

           URL obj = new URL(url);
           HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

           // optional default is GET
           con.setRequestMethod("GET");

           //add request header
           con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

           int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
           System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
           System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

           BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
           byte[] imageArray = new byte[1024];
           StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

           BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(httpServletResponse.getOutputStream());

           while ((in.read(imageArray)) != -1) {
               bout.write(imageArray);
           }
           System.out.println(response.toString());

           in.close();
           bout.close();
       }
   ```
3. Instead of calling directly third party server my Angular now calls my own server, see JS code below

   ```
   var iFrameDemo = angular.module("iFrameDemo", []);
   iFrameDemo.controller("iFrameDemoController", function ($scope, $sce, $http) {
       url = "/webApp/controller";
       $scope.iframesrcurl = url;
       console.log('iframesrcurl is ' + $scope.iframesrcurl);
   //    url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/angular/pic_angular.jpg?&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
       $scope.desiredFrameSource = url;
       $scope.errorImageSrc = '/webApp/images/thumb_down-512.png';

       var responsePromise = $http.get(url);//'http://localhost:8084/iframe/newLogin.html');

       responsePromise.success(function (data) {
           console.log("AJAX call was success " + data.found);
           $scope.iframesrcurl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
       });
       responsePromise.error(function () {
           console.log("AJAX call failed");
           $scope.iframesrcurl = $scope.errorImageSrc;
       });});
   ```
4. Declared Iframe in JSP file as

   ```
   <iframe ng-src="{{iframesrcurl}}" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="1100px" scrolling="auto" onload="iframeContentLoaded();" onerror="onerrorLoadingiFrame();"> 
      <h3>No such page</h3>
   </iframe>
   ```

That was it.. It worked like a charm than.. Please feel free to post if you have a better alternative to this. Hope this approach too helps someone..