# Is there anyway to check if the location of a html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there anyway to check if the location of a html `<a>` tag exists before leaving the page and display a message to the user rather than redirecting to a 404 page. I'm also using jQuery if that helps.

Something like this:

- When tag clicked run a method call a function
- Check if href of link
- Exists if link exists redirect
- Else display error message to user

Comment: Post some of the code you've tried.

Comment: Short answer: yes. Do you have the ability to check if a page exists (with your server)?

Comment: What do you mean by "check if href or link"??  That makes no sense to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922989/how-to-check-if-page-exists-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the page exists on the same domain or not. If you're trying to determine if a page on an external domain exists, it won't work - browser security prevents cross-domain calls (the same origin policy).

If it is on the same domain however, you can use jQuery like Buh Buh suggested. Although I'd recommend doing a HEAD-request instead of the GET-request the default `$.ajax()` method does - the `$.ajax()` method will download the entire page. Doing a HEAD request will only return the headers and indicate whether the page exists (response codes 200 - 299) or not (response codes 400 - 499).

Example:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'HEAD',  //HEAD request will only return the headers,with response codes 200 - 299
url: 'http://yoursite.com/page.html',
success: function() {
    // page exists
},
error: function() {
    // page does not exist
}
});
```