# How to check webpage is available or not using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make a web page request only if that web page is available. I have written my app using angularjs + javascript. Is there any way to determine whether a webpage is available or not using javascript ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if page exists using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922989/how-to-check-if-page-exists-using-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the page in question is on a different *origin*, you can't without using a server somewhere or relying on the other page implementing [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) and supporting your origin, because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

If the page in question is on the same origin, you can do an ajax call to query it:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("HEAD", url);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            // It worked
        } else {
            // It didn't
        }
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make an AJAX request with `XMLHttpRequest`, but instead of `POST` or `GET`, you should use the `HEAD` HTTP verb.