# HTML link to either local network or domain name

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

In my web page, I want to link to another web server in my local network.
I use `<a href="192.168.1.111:8080/index.jsp">`to do this when I am in local network. However, when I access the website outside the local network, I need to use domain name. `<a href="mydomain.com:8080/index.jsp">`

How can I do this in same page of code if I would access it from both LAN and WAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if it's an option, the easiest way to avoid this issue is using relative links. For example, if you're linking to another page on the same website, your link will always work if it's something like *"../directory/some-web-page.html"* rather than a full link with http included.

Otherwise, if you're linking to a completely different site, you could check whether your page exists on the local server using a very simple JQuery ajax request. If it doesn't exist, then assume you are not signed in to the same network and insert your remote domain name.

[As discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922989/how-to-check-if-page-exists-using-javascript), your simple ajax request can just fetch the HEAD of the locally hosted page, that way you're not fetching too much data and only confirming whether it exists. Your code could be something like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'path/to/your-file.html',
        type: 'HEAD',
        success: function() {
            // page exists
            // replace the href attribute with local host link
            document.getElementById('your-link').setAttribute('href', 'path/to/your-file.html');
        },
        error: function() {
            // page does not exist
            // do nothing, so your link sends user to remote site
        }
    });

});
```

And then, in your HTML, just include the link to your remote site like so:

```
<a id="your-link" href="yourremotesite.com">This is a link</a>
```

This should work on both a local and remote server without having to change the code.

**EDIT:**

I had to jump out of bed because another answer was just nagging at me...

You can also try accessing **window.location.host** or **window.location.hostname** and testing that in an if-statement to determine whether your page is on the local host or remote server.

Anyway, I hope one of these solutions helps. Good night and good luck!

Comment: I copied your code to mine, but the href="" does not change even i put `document.getElementById('your-link').setAttribute('href', 'path/to/your-file.html');` in both success and error

Comment: Make sure you change 'path/to/your/file' to the actual file path. That's meant as just placeholder text. Maybe this is causing the issue?

Comment: `url: '../faq.html'`,`document.getElementById('dd').setAttribute('href', '../faq.html');`,`<a id="dd" href="http://google.com/">` the webpage go to google instead of faq.html

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to include the jquery into the page. After that, it works. THX

Answer (score 1):

### HTML:

`<a href="" id="link">link</a>`

### javascript:

```
<script>
window.onload=myFunction;
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.domain;
    var a = document.getElementById('link');
    a.href = x + "/index.jsp";
}
</script>
```

Comment: However, my webpage is not the same ip with the jsp

Comment: e.g. My Page is 192.168.1.250/index.php. The link is 192.168.1.111:8080/index.jsp

Comment: In above ans, get current page's domain. If you want to get other server `192.168.1.250` then you have not dynamic that.