# Javascript for checking 404/500 pages/all links are clickable through

Tags: javascript

I've started using new tool,GI, for automated testing, and ill need to make javascript for testing the website's links, if they are clickable through, and there are no 404/500 pages on website. Ideally script should just include javascript code and be as simple as possible. Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: What is your question? What have you done so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922989/how-to-check-if-page-exists-using-javascript