# Get response code of a website using JS

Tags: javascript

How can I get response codes from site using JS? This is a site which I don't own. Is this possible?

For an example, I'm trying to make a script if that site loads, then show response in my website. I don't just want 200 or 404. I want every single status code shown for that site. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922989/how-to-check-if-page-exists-using-javascript

Comment: You've asked two different questions. _Getting response codes_ is one and determining _if that site loads_. These are different. Which do you want.

Comment: I don't just want 200 or 404. I want every single status code shown for that site.

Comment: You understand that they are not specific to a site, right?  HTTP Status Codes are a standard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: Yes, Alexander. For an example I tried making a JS script which shows the every status of  a website for an example bbc.com, and then implemented it on a test page I own. So visitor comes to my site and he can check the status of bbc from my site, whether it's down or now.

Comment: The issue I get is, not every response codes shown in my script. It logs in console but not in my script. And nothings wrong with my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible due to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). You can not get all HTTP response status codes from a website which you don't own. (unless CORS is enabled for all requesters)

Comment: I want to check, every status code on that site. I tried to achieve this but the response code I get is 0 for some statuses on my end. The console shows fine.

Comment: Randy Casburn, Can you please explain your opinion?

Comment: So that means no solution?

Comment: You can try using a free CORS Proxy. Or build your own one. But if your intention is to show your visitors what they get, then It won't work.

Comment: yes what i want is check the status code of that site from my website's visitors end.

Comment: Now that the OP has clarified `all status codes`, your answer is no wrong. The OP was unclear when saying _if that site loads_. Please make a simple edit so I can remove my downvote.

Comment: is this possible or not ? someone please tell me.